# Use Bootstrap buttons to scroll to different areas

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've got 2 bootstrap buttons I need to be able to scroll down the page. One goes to one section, and the other goes to a section further down the page. What do I need to add to my `<button>` elements?

```
<ul>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <li><button class="btn btn-block" style="margin-top: 5px;">Section1</button></li>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <li><button class="btn btn-block" style="margin-top: 5px;">Section2</button></li>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

I don't know Javascript at all, and I have minimal experience with jQuery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done with html. First, change your `<button>` tags to `<a>` tags

With the `<a>` tags, you can specify the `href` attribute as a div (or any element) to scroll to. So say you have an element:

`<div id="scroll-target"></div>`

You could rewrite your code as:

```
    <ul>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
    <li><a href="#scroll-target" class="btn btn-block" style="margin-top: 5px;">Section1</button> </li>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
    <li><a href="#scroll-target" class="btn btn-block" style="margin-top: 5px;">Section2</button> </li>
        </div<
    </ul>
```

And clicking on the buttons should take you to the `#scroll-target` div.

Also, I'm fairly certain the bootstrap styles will work just as well on `<a>` tags as they do on `<button>` tags with the same classes ('btn', 'btn-sm', 'btn-primary', etc.).

Comment: I think you're right about Bootstrap classes working the same on `a` elements. If they don't, you can always stick with buttons and add an event handler to change the `href`.

Comment: This answer is correct. Keep in mind that you should also add `role="button"` to your `<a>` tags so that screen readers know that those links are supposed to be/look like buttons. [Using the button role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_button_role)

Comment: Works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <ul>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <li><a href="#scroll-target" class="btn btn-block" style="margin-top: 5px;"><button class="btn btn-primary">
        Section1</button></li>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <li><a href="#scroll-target" class="btn btn-block" style="margin-top: 5px;"><button class="btn btn-primary">
          Section1</button></li>
      </div>
  </div>
</ul>

<div id="scroll-target"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @DFD It would be much better if you add explanation to your answer.